# Exclude url from rewriterule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I had to create new rule for htaccess. I wrote it. But I found problem with WSDL. When I use a new rule I have some problem with connection to WSDL. I don't know reasons. But I have to fix it.

Can I write in htaccess something such as (pseudocode):

```
if (http://www.mywebsite.com/mywebaplication/src/webServiceInstances.php?someGetParam) {
   RewriteRule ^([^\/]*)$ index.php?route=$1 [QSA]
} else {
   (RewriteRule...)

    RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)\.(html|xml|json|jhtml)$ public/index.php?module=$1&controller=Index&action=index&format=$2  [QSA]
    RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)$ public/index.php?module=$1&controller=Index&action=index&format=html  [QSA]
}
```

Thank for reply.

EDIT: this is my whole old rewrite

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

#php public/index.php -mconfigure
RewriteBase /webaplication/src/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^([^\/]*)$ index.php?route=$1 [QSA]

</IfModule>
```

this is my whole new rewrite

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On

#php public/index.php -mconfigure
RewriteBase /mywebaplication/src/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

#new way:   module     controller   method           format

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)/([a-zA-Z]+)/([a-zA-Z]+)\.(html|xml|json|jhtml)$ public/index.php?module=$1&controller=$2&action=$3&format=$4  [QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)/([a-zA-Z]+)/([a-zA-Z]+)$ public/index.php?module=$1&controller=$2&action=$3&format=html  [QSA]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)/([a-zA-Z]+)\.(html|xml|json|jhtml)$ public/index.php?module=$1&controller=$2&action=index&format=$3  [QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)/([a-zA-Z]+)$ public/index.php?module=$1&controller=$2&action=index&format=html  [QSA]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)\.(html|xml|json|jhtml)$ public/index.php?module=$1&controller=Index&action=index&format=$2  [QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)$ public/index.php?module=$1&controller=Index&action=index&format=html  [QSA]

#old way(this works for wsdl)
RewriteRule ^([^\/]*)$ index.php?route=$1 [QSA]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace all of your code with this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /webaplication/src/

RewriteRule ^(webServiceInstances\.php)$ index.php?route=$1 [QSA,L,NC]

# set default FMT to html
SetEnvIf Request_URI "^" FMT=html
# if a format is provided in URI then overwrite default FMT
SetEnvIf Request_URI "\.([^.]+)$" FMT=$1

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/.]+)(?:\.(?:html|xml|json|jhtml)|/?)$ public/index.php?module=$1&controller=$2&action=$3&format=%{ENV:FMT} [NC,L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/.]+)(?:\.(?:html|xml|json|jhtml)|/?)$ public/index.php?module=$1&controller=$2&action=index&format=%{ENV:FMT} [L,NC,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)(?:\.(?:html|xml|json|jhtml)|/?)$ public/index.php?module=$1&controller=Index&action=index&format=%{ENV:FMT} [L,NC,QSA]
```